# How to count 'single-word' substrings between commas

Tags: php

I have this string:

```
$array= 'orange, fruit, apple juice'
```

I want to count the single-word substrings in the string (orange/fruit)

I have tried

```
//Explode string at commas
$explode_tags = explode(",", $array);

//Check if space exists in substrings
foreach ($explode_tags as $explode_tag) {
  if (strstr(trim($explode_tag), ' ') == false) { 
  ...
  }
}
```

Now I can't figure out how to count the substrings only when the above IF statement comes false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
//Explode string at commas
$explode_tags = explode(",", $array);

$count = 0;
//Check if space exists in substrings
foreach ($explode_tags as $explode_tag) {
      if (strpos(trim($explode_tag), ' ') == false) { //strpos better for checking existance
          $count++;
      }
}

//Do something with $count
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$num = count(array_filter(explode(",",$array),function($a) {return !strpos(trim($a)," ")}));
```

Uses: [`count`](http://php.net/count), [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array-filter), [`explode`](http://php.net/explode), [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`trim`](http://php.net/trim).